# RabbitMQ closes socket while amqp_login call

Tags: c++, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I am using an example code from `..\rabbitmq-c\examples` in order to create a connection to my `http://localhost:15672`. 
From the following code block I get: `Logging in: socket is closed` output

```
  amqp_socket_t *socket = NULL;
  amqp_connection_state_t conn;

  hostname = "localhost";
  port = 131072;  // 15672 // 131072
  username = "guest";
  password = "guest";
  exchange = "testExchange";
  bindingKey = "testMessage";
  queueName = "testQueue";
  routingKey = "testMessage";
  messageBody = "testMessageBody";

  conn = amqp_new_connection();

  socket = amqp_tcp_socket_new(conn);
  if (!socket)
  {
    die("Creating TCP socket ERROR");
  }

  status = amqp_socket_open(socket, hostname, port);
  if (!status)
  {
    die("Opening TCP socket ERROR");
  }

  die_on_amqp_error(amqp_login(conn, "/", 0, 131072, 0, AMQP_SASL_METHOD_PLAIN,
    "guest", "guest"),
    "Logging in");
  amqp_channel_open(conn, 1);
  die_on_amqp_error(amqp_get_rpc_reply(conn), "Opening channel");
```

`rabbitmq-c` is compiled with VS2015 and I have `rabbitmq-server 3.7.6`, which is already running.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ runs on port `5672`, and you are trying to connect to port `131072`. Considering the maximum port allowed by TCP is `65535`, there's no way that is going to work.

Change you code to use `5672`.